# Encountering KeyError when trying to access 'wallets' from .yaml file

Tags: python, yaml

This is the code in my brownie-config.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
- OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
- smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
    - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
    - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2'
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
  from_mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}
```

Code in deploy_advanced.py:

```
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, network, config

def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    print(dev)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'wallets'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: i don't see where the yaml is read in with a yaml reader. does brownie parse that?

Comment: You probably need to load the content before you can access it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you placed the `.env` file (if used) and the `brownie-config.yaml` file in the root directory of your project. I got the same error because I added them within the scripts folder.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to load the content before you can access it:

```
import yaml

with open('brownie-config.yaml', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as yml:
    config = yaml.load(yml)

print(config['wallets']['from_key'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...I realised I didn't save the file properly. I put my project on autosave in vsc and it worked.

Comment: This answer is not really useful as `brownie` automatically does what is done in this answer...

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the variable names in the .env file and in the brownie-config.yml file did not match.

in my .env file i had:

```
wallets: 
    from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

and in my brownie-config.yml i had:

```
export PRIVATE_KEY1=0x4k54kl....
```

changing one to match the second fixed the error.